# extract score's sum for members and admin of a group grouped by admin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by

I have 2 table: scores and users:

```
user:
--------------
id | name | parent
--------------
1  | jack |0
--------------
2  | John |1
--------------
3  | Jim  |1
--------------
4  | Sara |0
--------------
5  | Ann  |4
--------------
6  | Suzi |4



score:
------------------------
id | title_id | user_id | score
------------------------
1  | 2        |0        |5
------------------------
2  | 4        |1        |4
------------------------
3  | 5        |1        |4
------------------------
```

parent is the admin of a group and i want to extract sum of scores for each group. Now i have this:

```
select sum(score) from score left join user on user.id=score.user_id where title_id=2 and parent!=0 group by parent_id
```

but this return only sum of group members and its not the sum of group. is there any better query?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following query does what you want.  It uses a `case` to distinguish between the group leader and the members, so all members (including the leader) are included:

```
select (case when u.parent_id = 0 then u.id else u.parent_id end) as grp, sum(s.score)
from user u left join
     score s
     on u.id = s.user_id and s.title_id = 2 
group by (case when u.parent_id = 0 then u.id else u.parent_id end);
```